# How to append data from another PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, append

I am using jQuery waterfall as a responsive grid layout.

I was using masonry, and had a load more button function but I am modifying what I have and trying to understand what the code does.

So for the load more button I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageIndex = 1;
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $("#buildcontainer").append('<div class="blogresults"><br><br></div>');
    });
});
```

In theory, this works fine. However I have another page which loads all of the extra content from my database.

This is what have used before:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageIndex = 1;
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $('.countvar').detach();
        $('#buildcontainer').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=' + type + '&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
           success: function(html) {
              var el = $(html);
         
              $("#buildcontainer").append(el);
              $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
              pageIndex++;
              
              var rowCount = $(".countvar").html();
              
              if (rowCount < 16) {
                $('#loadmorebuilds-div').remove(); 
                $('.countvar').detach();
              } else {
                $('.countvar').detach();
              }
              
           }
        
        });
        
    });
    
});
});
```

This also works, and does load the new data but seems to load the data and not fit it into the grid properly. One of the results sit underneath the others, but the other ones overlap in the top left and sit underneath others etc.

I can manually append as many divs using the first example and it works fine.

Also when using the second example the items seem to refresh and appose to just the new data being loaded.

In my eyes, its to do with this:

```
success: function(html) {
    var el = $(html);
```

Is there a better way to get the content from the requested page and simply append it back to the div.

The page that is called simply run a query on the database and echoes out the divs in a foreach statement. So the div layout would just be e.g.

```
<div class="blogresults"></div>
```

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: So the problem is this: "This also works, and does load the new data but seems to load the data and not fit it into the grid properly. One of the results sit underneath the others, but the other ones overlap in the top left and sit underneath others etc."? In that case, can't you edit the 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?' page so it returns the data differently?

Answer (score 0):

on the ajax success event you should do this:

```
    success: function(data) {
        $('blogresults').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searched arround the examples in the waterfall folder and it seemed to use a 'reflow' feature with works the same (i guess) and the masonry 'reload'.

Tried it as

```
$("#buildcontainer").append(html).waterfall('reflow');
```

And it works :)